# R function library() stopped working

Tags: r

Currently using R studio 0.98.1056 and R 3.1.1 and unexpectedly I was unable to upload any packages using library() or by clicking on the package itself. I keep getting the same error:

```
> library("class", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library")
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'is.component.class' not found
> library("gplots", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library")
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'is.component.class' not found
> library("gdata", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library")
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'is.component.class' not found
```

After going through a few suggestions I uninstalled R and R studio and deleted R.framework (sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework). I am still dealing with the same problem after reinstalling both programs. Has anyone encountered this issue and knows hot to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: I can't find any reference to a `is.component.class` function in the R source. Can you give the `traceback()` after the error to get a better idea where this message is coming from? When you start R, is a workspace being restored? Is there a reason you are explicitly setting the `lib.loc` in the `library()` call? Have you already installed these packages with `install.packages()`? Have you tried running this in the standard R GUI rather than R studio? Do you get the same error?

Comment: Have you redefined `library`? (what does `find('library')` return?

Comment: `is.component.class` is defined (at least) in [this package](https://github.com/joey711/phyloseq). Are you using this package?

Comment: Many thanks, MrFlick. Although I hadn't attached the package 'phyloseq' it was the source of this error. Once I cleared the workspace I got rid of the issue.